# Implicit declaration of recursive function in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have to evaluate this fraction using a recursive function where "n" is a count of fractions

[image]

But I get this errors: "implicit declaration of function" and "conflicting types"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("Enter size of n\n");
    int n;
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    float result = 2 / recursion(n); //implicit declaration of function
    printf("Result of dividing is = %f", result);

    return 0;
}

float recursion(int n) { //conflicting types

    float res = 2 + recursion(n - 1);

    return res;
}
```

Help me find out what's wrong with it

Comment: Put the function declaration `float recursion(int n);` above `main()`.

Comment: But you need to have a conditional in your recursive function to seperate the initial from the recursive case, and your recursive function should do some division!

Comment: The compiler sees you used `recursion` in `main` but it was not declared there yet. Move the function above it, or add `float recursion(int n);` at the top. (Then you'll find you have other problems--that's another question.)

Comment: other than the missing prototype declaration the program has a problem with the way he is calling the recursion.

Comment: The recursion does not seem to stop (infinite recursion) as there is no check for the base case(where recursion should end), you should add a condition, at which you want to stop the recursion, in the recursive function. As far as conflicting types are concerned, either give a prototype for your recursive function at the top, before main or define the function before main.

Comment: @Luchnik you should add stop condition & division in recursion function: http://ideone.com/pRuAaS

Comment: @Luchnik I am at your service sir

Comment: @0d0a Beautiful woman. She's very similar to my teacher of English at school. You're lucky

Comment: @Luchnik thank you, focus on mastering your C & C++ anyway ; )